# Where can I access H. Landolt's article/book on his Iodine Clock experiments?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, kinetics, history-of-chemistry, books

I simply want to take a look at Landolt's original writings and data so that I can make notes and reference it for a report I'm writing. I've looked everywhere on Google and I can't find anything other than articles that cite his work. It would be a great help if I can find a translated copy in a digital format.

Comment: Landolt, H. Ber. Dtsch. Chem. Ges. 1886, 19, 1317–1365. This is the original in German. A good college library in US should have access. You could also probably get a copy through your local library using inter-library loan.